# Tkinter unresponsive after clicking on Console

Tags: python, tkinter

[Tkinter Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZCmj.png) In my current project, I experience freezes in Tkinter.
Since I am in the process of polishing up, trying to squash bugs in the script, I figured out that these freezes happen when "clicking on stuff" in the console (marking stuff etc.). Accessing other programs (browsing etc.) works just fine. Since I'd like to narrow down (at least) any issues to my sloppy programming, I'd like to know what's the root of the problem or whether I can avoid it. I've read that some freezing issues are due to "threading" ... That I could understand, but the following example is rather simple.

The following MWE causes the issue. Steps to reproduce: Run code with python.exe, click button, mark "derp" in the console, watch tkinter freezing.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def start_print():
    print('derp')
    #root.after(6000, start_print)

start_button = Button(root, text = 'Derp', command = start_print)
start_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!
Jan

Comment: Nothing strange happens here, also your code seems fine to me.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, exactly as I would expect.

Comment: It is not the code that causes the issue. It is "interacting" with the console and switching back to the GUI. I've added an image to the post above. I've experienced the same issue on two computers, both Win10-64bit.

Comment: I am experiencing the error rather with steps: _"Run code with python.exe, click button, start marking, click the button while the marking is still on going, watch tkinter freezing"_

Comment: Also further note that closing can be done, only the button seems to be stuck.

Comment: The absolute [mcve] that I could produce was `from tkinter import *; Button(command = print).pack(); mainloop()`.

Comment: Seems to be behaving this way with "Select All" option used as well.

Comment: This is quote minimal MCVE :)